# Can I use one viewController instead of 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want the user to enter 5 details about himself but I don't want to use a boring 5 textfield form. I want the user to see one text field at a time -> click the button and move to the next text field.
My question is, do I have to use 5 viewcontrollers for this? I'm trying to find a more elegant way.

I thought about something like `setHidden:YES` for every used textfield but it's not animated and looks kinda ugly so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: You can use a UIScrollView with paging set to enabled

Comment: You may use a very simple animations.

Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11934604/1032151

Comment: Why do you need 5 different text fields? Use a label displaying the title of the detail to insert, then when the user inserts it, just change the title of the label and use the same text field.

Comment: Are you sure you want to design your application like this? Ask anyone who's slogged through a "slide show" in a Web page how they feel about it.

Comment: @trudyscousin I think that 1 2 3 step is a bit nicer than seeing the 3 steps in advance. It's just name, age etc.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii Very cool. Is there a way to add fading to it while it scrolls off the screen?

Comment: yepp, just set alpha value and it will be animated as well

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii for some reason setting something like `    myTextLabel.alpha = 0.0;` just makes it disappear with no animation

Comment: Make sure you place myTextLabel.alpha = 0.0; among [UIView beginAnimations:@"myAnimation" context:nil]; and [UIView commitAnimations]; if that's so and still no animation, something is wrong in your other code. This one should work for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use only one `UIViewController` `(DetailViewController)` with one `UIView` as container `(DetailViewContainer)`, this container holds your 5 detailed `UIView` `(DetailView)`. If you want specific transition animation between each `DetailView` you can implement your transition animation inside `DetailViewContainer`.

If I should to do same task as you I would do it in the following way:

```
typedef enum
{
    firstDetailView,
    secondDetailView,
        ...
}DetailViewType;

@protocol DetailViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)detailViewDidEndEditingWithValue:(NSString)value detailViewType:(DetailViewType)detailViewType;

@end

//

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <DetailViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation DetailViewController
- (void)detailViewDidEndEditingWithValue:(NSString)value detailViewType:(DetailViewType)detailViewType
{
    //save new detail to model here
}
@end

//

@interface DetailView : UIView
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<DetailViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation DetailView
- (void)saveDetailValue
{
    [delegate detailViewDidEndEditingWithValue:self.value detailViewType:self.type];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are tons of ways you could approach this, but to specifically answer your question about having to use 5 view controllers... no.  You wouldn't have to.  You could create a say... "QuestionViewController" that handles displaying the question and then keeps pushing new instances of that controller onto the navigation stack with different questions.

**.h**

```
@interface QuestionViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *question;

- (IBAction) nextQuestion:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "QuestionViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation QuestionViewController

@synthesize question = _question;


- (IBAction)nextQuestion:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    QuestionViewController *vc = [[QuestionViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"QuestionViewController"
                                                                          bundle:nil];

    vc.question = [delegate getNextQuestion];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc
                                         animated:YES];
}

@end
```

So in my example, the app delegate would manage which question comes next and then the question view controller would simply fetch the next question and push a new instance of itself onto the view stack.  You could wire a button up to the **nextQuestion:(id)sender** action.  This should be enough to get you going if you decide to stick with the "one question per controller" idea.

Like I said, I'm not weighing in on what type of design is the best.  I'm just saying if you want to do it the way you described... this would keep you from having to create a bunch of similar controllers.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use one ViewController per Page
If your textfields are on the same page, then you should use one viewController with 5 subviews.

Use `view setHidden`, but if you want ananimation, then simple animate to full transparent color (using `view.alpha = 0.0`) , then hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can really go wild with this, and use something like a `IBoutletCollection` with your 5 `UITextFields`. You can then easily manage whats the correct `UITextField` to show (based on the index of the question):

```
Question 1 => UITextField (0)
Question 2 => UITextField (1)
```

You can then use what Wojtek suggested: a nice animation with some effects.

Answer (score 0):

A single text field and label (for the question) would do. Your single view controller could change the question and empty the text field every time when a new question is due. There is no need to hassle with 4 hidden views/pairs of views and 1 visible.

If you want to go for some basic animations "for free" then go for a UISlider with paging enabled, carrying 5 pairs of label and text field.

Answer (score -1):

If you want simple fade-in/out transition you can do it this way

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    if(something)
    //fade in
    view.alpha = 1.f;
    else {
    //fade out
 view.alpha = 0.f;
    view.hidden = YES;
}];
```

Comment: You sure it should be `[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{` ?

Comment: Yes, I am, why are you asking ?